# Loading hi-res music from mac mini to iphone - sample rate not supported

Tags: iphone, ios, music, mac-mini

I have a Mac mini late 2014 with macOS Catalina (10.15.7).

I have an iPhone 12 mini with iOS 15.6.1.

In iTunes, I try to sync 192 kHz/24 bit songs, but get the error "sample rate not supported by the iPhone".

The apple spec just says that the phone can play lossless, but nothing about sample rate (https://support.apple.com/kb/SP829?locale=en_US)

Is this correct, or is there a problem with the phone? Is there anything I can do to my phone so it can play 192 kHz?

(I already know that I can downgrade the song to 96 kHz on my mac.)

Comment: I don’t have all the specs for an answer, but my iPhone couldn’t play a majority of my HiRes music which is why I switched to a Sony Walkman HiRes player (NW-A55).  I hardly use my iPhone for music anymore,

Comment: I'd upvote an answer that walked me through your setup @Allan - how you manage the library on the alternative player, etc...

Comment: I ‘ll write up something tomorrow @bmike  I’m on my iPad and my solution involves `rsync`, [MusicBrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/), and [Strawberry Music Player](https://strawberrymusicplayer.org/). A bit too much to type on a virtual keyboard. :-)

Comment: The cynic in me wants to know 1) who masters at 48/192? 2) is the DAC on a phone good enough to differentiate? 3) Is your repro gear good enough to differentiate? …& the late 4) Do you have the ears to differentiate, blind test? The implicit challenge being, "Can you hear aliasing near Nyquist when the sample rate is even 48kHz?"